# How can I use a [Shortcode] in my custom field wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a custom wordpress `post.php`, all posts within a specific category will use this template. In nearly every post there will be scrolling testimonials, to handle this I am using a layer slider.

Within the page I have a custom field of testimonial that is filled with something like `[layreslider  id="2"]`
In my php file I have:

```
<div class="trips-testimonials">
    <?php do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'testimonial', true)); ?>
</div>
```

This seems to do nothing. If I add echo to the PHP:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post-ID, 'testimonial', true)); ?>
```

I get the output of `[layreslider  id="2"]`

Here is a sample page, the blue box under the photo is where the slider should show up. 
http://www.ct-social.com/ctsdev/aff/capri/

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you miss the > from post Id so it should read

```
<?php do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'testimonial', true)); ?>
```

Also you may need to call global $post; if outside the loop.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part in the question. The code is accurate and reads the way you displayed. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, what happens if you assign the get_post_meta to a variable and then include the variable inside do_shortcode? As according to codex the short code needs to be in single quotes: echo do_shortcode('[gallery]');

Comment: $ttm = get_post_meta($post ->ID, "testimonial", TRUE);
<?php echo do_shortcode('$ttm'); ?>
Returns $ttm
Without the single quotes still returns [layerslider id="2"]